# Download files in the background and show progress in an android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, intentservice

I have a use cases (which might appear as a very common use case). I want to download some files from my server and show the progress on a `Fragment`. For implementing the download part, what is the prescribed way? I have two ways in my mind by which we might implement this:

1. Using an `IntentService`in the background and downloading all the files there. The service would sends out broadcasts to update the UI on my `Fragment`.

OR

2. I use the design pattern mentioned in [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java) url. Here, the background task is run using a separate fragment and using `setRetainInstance(true)`, so that we ensure that the process is still running in the background and is not restarted once the activity gets started due to configuration changes.

I see both of the above as possible solutions in case of downloading files. But, which one is a **better** solution. If one is better than the other then what are the scenarios in which the other solution is used?

Comment: Use the first option, it's surely the best.
The second option i think it's not correct, setRetainInstance should not be used to perform background operation, it should be used only when you are performing small operations (network and not) on fragments and you don't want them to be recreated on activity configuration changes.

Comment: or you can just download a file in async task and update it progress in OnProgressUpdate() method

Comment: @Redman: I have been reading a lot about `AsyncTask`(s) and people usually suggest not to use it for tasks like downloading files in the background and showing the progress. For a comprehensive detail have a look at this blog post http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: Async task can be used to download file and updating UI.